# Must I use "date" data type to animate data by year?

Tags: carto, torque

I'm trying to animate the opening and closing of businesses by year but my data column is set to "number" not "date".  The animation is not working in that all the data points show up at once, rather than appear and disappear according to the year.  I tried changing the number of steps to correlate with the number of years but that hasn't worked either.  I'm wondering if the data type is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your number column to a date column by first creating a new column (button in the lower right corner), selecting 'date' as the data type, and then running the following SQL command to convert the numeric year to a date type:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET new_date_column = to_char(yr_num_column, 'YYYY')::date
```

You will obviously have to change `table_name` to the name of your table, `new_date_column` to the new column you just created, and `yr_num_column` to be the name of the column you already have that has the years. This statement writes to your table and cannot be reversed so be sure that you get everything correct before running it.

After that, choose 'Torque' in your visualization wizard and select the new date column.